# How to prevent Dynamics Solution from overwriting forms

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We are building a Managed Solution for Dynamics using 2013 on-prem. We are including fields on standard object like Account/Lead/Opportunity

However, our managed package contains Forms, fields, etc that we have not customized.  This overwrites customizations in the target orgs (our customers' CRM)

I know that in 2016, you get to pick and choose your fields and forms, but I wanted to achieve same thing for our customer using older versions of dynamics.

Is there any way to achieve this with 2013?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a managed solution, you get the option to 'Overwrite or Maintain Customizations'. [image: Options to overwrite customizations]
If you select Maintain Customizations this normally should work if the customizations from the customers are unmanaged.